# How to navigate to a specific destination via deep link without adding any other destination in the backstack

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

Suppose I have the following setup:

---

**nav_graph_a.xml**
Fragment A (start destination)
includes nav_graph_b

**nav_graph_b.xml**
Fragment B (start destination)
Fragment C (has a deep link to it)

And an Activity that has **nav_graph_a** in it.

---

If I try to navigate through deep link to Fragment C, a backstack will be automatically built with Fragment A and Fragment B in it.

**How can I navigate through deep link to Fragment C without adding any other fragment to the backstack?**

Comment: How are you launching you deep link? The behavior differs whether the app launches your deep link with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as explained in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#implicit). You already won't get any synthetic back stack if you are on the other app's task stack.

Comment: I am launching via adb or via an external link.

Comment: What does "via an external link" mean? Please be specific.

Comment: Suppose I have added the following deep link to a fragment in my nav graph: `<deepLink android:id="@+id/some_deep_link_id" app:uri="myapp://cities/{city_id}" />`. If I open Chrome on the device and paste the following link in the address bar "myapp://cities/123" I will be redirected to my app.